# Get pid of application started by mvn exec plugin

Tags: unix, maven, sh

I want to write .sh script that will kill process started by maven exec plugin. At the moment i'm trying to get PID by start time, but this approach do not guarantee that there is no some collision with other processes.

Please, could someone say whether there is an approach to get PID or to kill process started by mvn exec .

Thanks.

Comment: does unix has the concept of a process hierachy? If yes you could look for child processes of the maven build.

Comment: Where would you get the PID from, if you're killing from another process? Your best bet would be to add some identifiable command line arguments to the forked process and base your kill on that.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to start the maven process using start-stop-daemon. I use a modified bash script from a tomcat init.d to start/stop java or maven programs as daemons. Here is a snippet. Please customize as needed:

```
#!/bin/sh    
case "$1" in
      start)
            log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
            start-stop-daemon --start -b -u "$MAVEN_USER" -g "$MAVEN_GROUP" \
                    -c "$MAVEN_USER" -d "$MAVEN_HOME" -p "$MAVEN_PID" -m \
                    -x mvn -- exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.company.Application" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -Dexec.args="/home/user 192.168.1.1" 2>&1
            status="$?"
            set +a -e
            else
                log_progress_msg "(already running)"
                    log_end_msg 0
            fi
            ;;
      stop)
            log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"

            set +e
            if [ -f "$MAVEN_PID" ]; then
                    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile "$MAVEN_PID" \
                            --user "$MAVEN_USER" \
                            --retry=TERM/20/KILL/5 >/dev/null
                    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
                            log_progress_msg "$DESC is not running but pid file exists, cleaning up"
                    elif [ $? -eq 3 ]; then
                            PID="`cat $MAVEN_PID`"
                            log_failure_msg "Failed to stop $NAME (pid $PID)"
                            exit 1
                    fi
                    rm -f "$MAVEN_PID"
                    rm -rf "$JVM_TMP"
            else
                    log_progress_msg "(not running)"
            fi
            log_end_msg 0
            set -e
            ;;
```